# Write the expression in terms of $\sin$ only $\sin(4x)-\cos(4x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently taking a Precalc II (Trig) course in college. There is a question in the book that I can't figure out how to complete it. The question follows:

Write the expression in terms of sine only:

$\sin(4x)-\cos(4x)$

So far I have $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=k\cdot\sin(x+\theta)$

I believe I have found k: $k=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{2}$

So I think it would be $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sin(4x+\theta)$ but I do not know how I would find $\theta$.

Thanks in advance for all of your help. You have no idea how much I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin(4x)-\cos(4x)=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\sin(4x)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\cos(4x)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=$$

$$\sqrt{2}\sin(4x-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$$

so your $ \theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}$.

Comment: This is similar to what I think the answer is supposed to be. The question before the one I asked had the answer in the back of the book and it looks exactly like this but different values. I was confused about how to actually find the last value, but now I clearly see how to do so. Thanks very much!

Comment: @BlazeRyder Thanks for your question . Thanks for your comment. But some unknowns will make me loosing points for No reason.

Answer (score 2):

Use that

$$\cos(4x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)=1-2(2\sin x \cos x)^2=1-8\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the two double angle identities that you know:
\begin{align}
\sin2\theta&=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
\cos2\theta&=1-2\sin^2\theta
\end{align}
You will also need to know
$$\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$

As such, we get
\begin{align}
\sin4x-\cos4x&=\sin2(2x)-\cos2(2x)\\
&=2\sin2x\cos2x-(1-2\sin^22x)\\
&=2(2\sin x\cos x)(1-2\sin^2x)+1+2(2\sin x\cos x)^2\\
&=2\sin x\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}(1-2\sin^2x)+1+8\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)\\
&=2\sin x\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}-4\sin^3x\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}+1+8\sin^2x-8\sin^4x
\end{align}

Comment: I'd like to point out:  if the question then asked you to evaluate the expression given a particular value for $\sin x$, then instead of writing $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$, we can simply solve for $\cos x$ using the Pythagorean theorem.